# ThreadAbortException occurs on [VSTO] sometimes, no regule

Tags: vsto

I just get this exception message sometimes, but i do not know how to make it appear every time.

```
details:
************* Exception Text *******************
System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thrad was being aborted.
at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DefWindProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Form.DefWindProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WindProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WindProc(Message& m)
at System.Windows.Forms.ContianerControl.WindProc(Message& m)
...and so on
```

Give me some advise please?

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the user is closing **Outlook** (*`outlook.exe` process ending*) and you have code that is still executing. During exit, you can handle the `ThreadAbortException` and react to it to preserve any state before the application ends.

Comment: my application is developed with VSTO, is using for EXCEL.

Comment: How could I get the executing Code?

Comment: You would need a [`try`/`catch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) around your custom code ([*`ThisAddIn.ThisAddIn_Startup`*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.addinbase.startup.aspx)) and you could log the error message or react to it via other means.